# Find my Māori pronouns

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

The [Māori language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C4%81ori_language) has quite simple pronouns. It uses a single word for he/she/they/etc (`ia`), and the words for "you" and "me" are `koe` and `au` respectively.

There are also words for groups of exactly two people:

- `tāua` - You and me (we, `au` and `koe`)
- `māua` - Me and them (we, `au` and `ia`)
- `rāua` - Them (third person plural - two of them, `ia` and `ia`)
- `kōrua` - You two (`koe` and `koe`)

And for three or more people:

- `tātou` - All of you and me (we, `au` and multiple `koe`)
- `mātou` - Me and all of them (we, `au` and multiple `ia`)
- `rātou` - All of them (third person plural, multiple `ia`)
- `koutou` - All of you (multiple `koe`)

Your challenge is to take a list of `ia`, `koe` and `au` and return the correct pronoun. You may assume that there is at most one `au` and that `ia` and `koe` will never both be in the input.

You may take input in any reasonable format - An array of `ia`, `koe` and `au` or three distinct values (within reason) representing those, an array of the counts of each word, a dictionary containing the counts of each word, space-separated words etc.

When there is only one word, you should output that.

Note that some of the outputs contain Unicode (`ā` and `ō`). You may output these as they are or as double letters - `aa` and `oo`.

For example, `ia ia` becomes `rāua` as it is two `ia`. `au ia ia ia ia` becomes `mātou` as it is one `au` and more than two `ia`. `koe koe` becomes `kōrua`.

## Testcases

```
ia -> ia
koe -> koe
koe au -> tāua
ia ia -> rāua
koe koe koe koe koe -> koutou
ia ia au ia -> mātou
ia ia ia ia ia ia ia -> rātou
```

Comment: What should I do for `au au`, `au au au`, `au koe ia`, `koe ia`, `koe koe ia`, `koe ia ia`, `koe koe ia ia`?

Comment: @tsh "You may assume that there is at most one `au` and that `ia` and `koe` will never both be in the input."

Comment: Suggest add 1 test cases for every possible output.

Comment: Should "groups of two or more people" be only "groups of (exactly) two people"?

Comment: @att Yes, it should.

Comment: While it's not relevant to the puzzle, since explicitly avoided, I'm still curious what the answer would have been to tsh's question if that were not the case. Are there other group pronouns, not described here? Or does (koe ia) get treated as (koe koe)?

Comment: @DewiMorgan I'm not quite sure about this but I think you're correct with that - In English "You and Bob" could be "You two" but not "Them two"

Comment: @DewiMorgan: Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clusivity#Second-person_clusivity) that there is controversy over whether the distinction between (koe ia) and (koe koe) is expressed in any natural language at all, or indeed whether the human brain is even capable of consistently making such a distinction. I think the latter sounds a bit hyperbolic to me.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 94 bytes

```javascript
a=>(g=r=>!!a.match(r))` `?'krtm'[h=g`u`*2+g`i`]+(g` .* `?h?'aatou':'outou':h?'aaua':'oorua'):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzLCoMwEEX3/Yq4SqLURZdC9ENKYQarMfUxEpP@fpraVSXCDBfOnTkvfOPWWrO660LPLvQqoKqFVlbVWYbljK4dhJUSGDR8tG7m90Fp8JDfCg0GHoXQwMo81kPDER15XnHye@7E4xeQjSkrDC0tG01dOZEWveAmUnk5wJG6NGXoE4VBdqZhhz37juK049f@TzwLHw)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 121 bytes

```javascript
x=>x[1]?'koutou0tātou0rātou0mātou0kōrua0tāua0rāua0māua'.split(0)[g=y=>x.includes(y+''),g`au`+g`ia`*2+4*!x[2]]:x[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBLDsIgEN33FHVVsIrVuNJUD9I0gVQkWFoaWgwuPYC30nPVAVyZMPOGeW8@cGN3NjZGDtO61xc@X8vZlSdXbetz1mo7aVtM76cHE6GL0H5exjLPgTfBd95nZByUnFCBK1E@oBORfaPshY/okWcZXgnKLM0FlYwud/l@uXDVrq4Prirq@ZhAOl2fUsmSVnMfAYSQWX8L4xLQRFmYG@h/C5V@@58YymNJXP@X/TuxI9CUGD4o1nC0ITk6l8DgjVjBxzS6H7XiRGmBrsjFx9KUYoznLw)

Tabling n>2, "ia" exist, and "au" exist

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 53 bytes

```
≔№θ η¿¬ηθ«≔⁺∧№θia²№θauζ¿ζ⁺§rtmζaa¿⊖ηkou¦koor¿⊖ηtou¦ua
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY67DsIwDEXn9iusTIlUFlamChYW1F@IWkOjtonIA6Eivj3EhUAXBi/X9xy77aVtjRxjrJ1TF833JmjPrxUwYKKCXuxKdQZ@Mp73QkBjFa1TiqNDeJTFh2vG4Hitu5VASTJs0/wyGZhIwZwEBXnnrHzz/qg7vHNm/cSoRUSyUHu5R8gBW4sTao/d6iU2mKTOvW9mLMun/nB@4WCNBUnQM0YZYDCYp4yb2/gC) Link is to verbose version of code. Output uses double vowels. Explanation:

```
≔№θ η
```

Count the number of spaces in the input. (Note that due to Charcoal's input format autodetection, you need a trailing newline in the input for this to work.)

```
¿¬ηθ«
```

If there are no spaces, then just print the input.

```
≔⁺∧№θia²№θauζ
```

Count `2` if `ia` is present, plus `1` if a (assumed single) `au` is present.

```
¿ζ⁺§rtmζaa
```

If either are present then output `taa`, `maa` or `raa` as appropriate, ...

```
¿⊖ηkou¦koor
```

... otherwise output `kou` or `koor` depending on the number of words.

```
¿⊖ηtou¦ua
```

Output `tou` or `ua` depending on the number of words.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 124 bytes

```python
lambda n:[n,'rmkt'[2*('k'in n)+('u'in n)]+['ou','oa'['a'in n]*2][[*n].count('k')<3]+['ua','tou'][len(n.split())>2]][' 'in n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDBbsMgDL3nK6xeHNKoh/QyVWt/hKLKaxIVJTGIgLTt5zMI6apNwtjwnt8z2C//MHx8s27pz9dlpOmjJeCT5BrdNHiUTVXigJqBxb7EkCu1l2gC1mgIJdJ6qapGSVmxOtxNYJ@6xPsxMQNFpo98JceOSz7MdtS@FOLSKCURcvui2d5m7@AMiKipGEyXAigUmiBfwL/ISKQkPNd/V5Ta7PDKKIqi@7Td3XftzQRvg09ukZjkPFEgcOs@RNQEmIhScmt6CkWR3jiI49bwVIsn@Na23N7wAjYbcSrAOh2/pU8cUUfXGfyjg22MpLjDOqviDojbFf412Hh6xpe4WH4A)

Comment: I recommend changing the online test output to `print(f"[{'OK' if f(inp) == expected else 'FAIL, expected ' + expected}] {inp} -> {f(inp)}")`, makes it look nicer!

Comment: @rebane2001 Okay, will do that in the future!

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>110</s> 79 bytes

```
^(?=(.*au)?)(?=(?<1>.*ia)?){2}\w+ \w+
$#1aaua
T`d`ktmr
ua .*
tou
kaa
kou
uu
oru
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP07D3lZDTyuxVNNeE8S0tzG009PKTARyq41qY8q1FYCYS0XZMDGxNJErJCElIbskt4irNFFBT4urJL@UKzsxkSsbSJeWcuUXlf7/nwnipoKwQmIpV2aiAkRAAQ1DZIBKQPIQNioCAA) Link includes test cases. Output uses double vowels as those accented characters aren't in Retina's default code page. Explanation:

```
^(?=(.*au)?)(?=(?<1>.*ia)?){2}\w+ \w+
```

See whether the input contains `au`, matching as `$#1`, plus add two further matches to `$#1` if the input contains `ia`. Also delete two words from the input (this fails if the input only contains one word).

```
$#1aaua
```

Replace the first two words with the count of matches suffixed with `aaua`.

```
T`d`ktmr
```

Replace the count with the appropriate letter.

```
ua .*
tou
```

If there were more than two words then change the `ua` to `tou`.

```
kaa
kou
```

`kaatou` should be `koutou`.

```
uu
oru
```

But `kouua` should be `koorua`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-apl`, 71 bytes

```ruby
k=$F[2]?:koutou: :kōrua;$_=!/a/?k:(/k/??t:/u/??m:?r)+?ā+k[3,3]if$F[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P9tWxS3aKNbeKju/tCS/1ErBKvtob1FporVKvK2ifqK@fbaVhn62vr19iZV@KZDKtbIv0tS2P9KonR1trGMcm5kG1G8Y@/9/ZiJXdn4qV2IpiFIAUomlChAxBZB4ZiISTwGqCg1DFClANELYqOhffkFJZn5e8X/dxIIcAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>57 52 51 49</s>  47 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“mtr”;€⁾aa;“kou“koor”⁽ñỌ,ḥ;Lị““ua“tou”Ɗ
Ṣḣ3ÇḢḊ?
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of characters that yields a list of characters, the pronoun.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zckqJHDXOtHzWtedS4LzHRGiiUnV8KJvNBMo8a9x7e@HB3j87DHUutfR7u7gZKAVFpIpAoASmce6yL6@HORQ93LDY@3P5wB5DRZf////9o9cxEdR0FFDKxFMqOBQA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zckqJHDXOtHzWtedS4LzHRGiiUnV8KJvNBMo8a9x7e@HB3j87DHUutfR7u7gZKAVFpIpAoASmce6yL6@HORQ93LDY@3P5wB5DRZf//4e4tD3dsAhp6uB1IRP7/n5nIlZ2fCsIKiaVcmYkKEAEFNAyRASoByUPYqAgA).

#### How?

```
“mtr”;€⁾aa;“kou“koor”... - Link 1: list of lists of characters, X
“mtr”                    - "mtr"
       ⁾aa               - "aa"
     ;€                  - concatenate each -> ["maa", "taa", "raa"]
           “kou“koor”    - ["kou", "koor"]
          ;              - concatenate
                         -> domain = ["maa", "taa", "raa", "kou", "koor"]

...⁽ñỌ,ḥ;Lị““ua“tou”Ɗ - Link 1 (continued)
   ⁽ñỌ                - 7932
      ,               - pair
       ḥ              - hash X with a salt of 7932 and our domain (from above)
                    Ɗ - last three links as a monad - f(X):
         L            -   length (2 or 3)
           ““ua“tou”  -   ["", "ua", "tou"]
          ị           -   index into
        ;             - concatenate

Ṣḣ3ÇḢḊ? - Main Link: list of lists of characters, I
Ṣ       - sort I
 ḣ3     - keep up to the first three
      ? - if...
     Ḋ  - ...condition: dequeue (i.e. is length > 1 ?)
   Ç    - ...then: call Link 1
    Ḣ   - ...else: head of I
```